# How to fix nav bar to bottom of the screen for mobile view>

Tags: html, css

I currently have a sidebar as a navigation bar when I am viewing on desktop. In the desktop the view, the icons and text are side-by-side with the icons on the left, and the text on the right.

I was trying get it so that when it collapses down to mobile view, the sidebar to collapse to a nav bar that's fixed to the bottom of the screen. With the icons on top and centered underneath the text.

This is currently what I have: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpRgEJ

This is my code for trying to get to to position at the bottom:

```
@media (max-width:35em) {

    .main-nav {
        background: #ECC264;
        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        height: 5em;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

It currently collapses into a top nav bar, and the icons and text are side-by-side as opposed to being top-and-bottom.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, i suggest you to organize your CSS as the following:

1.- General selectors and clases with rules that will affect everything

2.- Media Queries that affect only the behavior for certain width.

So if you need a navbar that is always fixed, but for desktop is positioned on the left side of the screen and for mobile is on the bottom of the page you should write something like this:

```
.sidebar{ /* Every rule that will be always visible, something like colors, fonts, etc. */
  background-color: yellow; 
  position: fixed;
}

@media(min-width:35.1em){ /* Larger than mobile devices */
  .sidebar{
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 40px;
  }
}

@media(max-width:35em){ /* Breakpoint only for mobile */
  .sidebar{
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

In that way you will avoid dealing with rules that doesn't match together.

Your complete CSS should look like this:

```
.fa-2x {
    font-size: 2rem;
}
.fa {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 2rem;
}

.main-nav {
    background: #ECC264;
    border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.main-nav>ul {
    margin: 0rem 0rem;
}

nav ul,
nav li {
    outline: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.main-nav li:hover>a,
nav.main-nav li.active>a{
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #919191;
}

.main-nav .nav-text, .main-nav li>a{
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.main-nav li>a {
      border-collapse: collapse;
      border-spacing: 0;
      color: white;
      font-size: 1.03rem;
      text-decoration: none;
}

@media (min-width:35.1em) {
  .fa{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 5rem;
    height: 5rem;
  }

  .main-nav:hover,
nav.main-nav.expanded {
    width: 15em;
    overflow: visible;
}

  .main-nav{
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    width: 5rem;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
    transition: width .05s linear;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
  }

  .main-nav li {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 18rem;
  }
  .main-nav li>a {
      position: relative;
      display: table;
      -webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
      -webkit-transition: all .1s linear;
      transition: all .1s linear;
  }

  .main-nav .nav-text {
      position: relative;
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
      width: 10rem;
  }
}


@media (max-width:35em) {

    .main-nav {
        background: #ECC264;
        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        position: fixed;
        margin: 0;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        /*height: 5em;*/
        width: 100%;
    }

  .main-nav ul{
    display: table;
    width: 100%; 
  }

    .main-nav li{
      float: left;
      width: 25%;
      list-style-type: none;
      text-align: center;
    }

  .main-nav a{
    display: block;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 74px;
  }

  .main-nav i, .main-nav span{
    display: block;
  }

  .main-nav span{
    font-size: 14px;
  }
}
```

Your example forked in Codepen: http://codepen.io/xWaZzo/pen/BKZpQE

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
 #myNavbar {
        position: relative;
    }

    #myNavbar .nav {
        position: absolute; 
        bottom: 0; 
        right: 0;
        margin-bottom: -10px;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/1819/

Comment: Hi, that code looks to be for a fixed top nav, which is the complete opposite of what I'm looking for.

Comment: http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=navbar-fixed-to-bottom follow this link

Answer (score 0):

You should remove top:0 from

```
.main-nav {
background: #ECC264;
border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
position: fixed;
/ *top: 0;*/
bottom: 0;
height: 100%;
left: 0;
width: 5rem;
overflow: hidden;
-webkit-transition: width .05s linear;
transition: width .05s linear;
-webkit-transform: translateZ(0) scale(1, 1);
}
```

Also increase height in media query class

```
@media (max-width:35em) {

.main-nav {
background: #ECC264;
border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
position: relative;
margin: 0;
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
height: 20em;
width: 100%;
}
}
```

Hope this is you want?